# ListView.builder doesn't work in alertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use ListView.builder to show image. it is works when i show it in main page but when i use it in alertDialog it doesn't work at all. This is my code for alertDialog.

```
void rateVideo(BuildContext context){
var alertDialog = AlertDialog(
  title: Text("video rate"),
  content: RateClip(),
  actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              child: Text('ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                //rateVideo(context);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }),
        ],
);
showDialog(context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context){
  return alertDialog;
}
);
}
```

and this code is about ListView.builder that i try to show images

```
class RateClip extends StatelessWidget {
//const ActivityClip ({Key key}) : super(key: key);
final List<String> pic = [
 'assets/images/LG5.png',
 'assets/images/stress.png',
 'assets/images/stress.png',
 'assets/images/normal.png',
 'assets/images/happy.png'
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    height: 60,
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: pic.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              width: 30,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                    },
                    child: Image.asset(pic[index].toString(), height: 30, width: 30),
                  )]));
        }));  
       }



       }
```

Comment: define `"it doesn't work at all."` - and why do you have `ListView` as a item in your `ListView.builder` (even more interesting that it has only one child)?

Comment: From your seggest I fix it already. Now my code has no ListView but the result still the same.

Comment: i post my new code in below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from error it is assertion error of alert dialog. Element in alert dialog must be specific width, which you can see in log. it change based on device.

So to solve your error you have to provide specific width of container, which is above list view. To be more specific it is because your listview is horizontal and set width to infinity and that’s why it is throwing assertion error. If is was vertical listview then you have to provide height of container.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.75 // here i set width of container to 75% of screen 
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my new code

```
class RateClip extends StatelessWidget {
//const ActivityClip ({Key key}) : super(key: key);
final List<String> pic = [
'assets/images/LG5.png',
'assets/images/stress.png',
'assets/images/stress.png',
'assets/images/normal.png',
'assets/images/happy.png'
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 200),
    height: 60,
    //width: 40,
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: pic.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                    },
                    child: Image.asset(pic[index].toString(), height: 30, width: 30),
                  );
        }));  
        }



       }
```